# Print the following pattern for the given number of rows

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

can you please assist with code for to print the below in python

```
4444444
4333334
4322234
4321234
4322234
4333334  
4444444
```

i tried the below however since i am new was little confused which code to be used
how do we get the numbers in the below order

Comment: You said "I tried the below", but there's no code here.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_pattern():
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(7):
        if abs(3 - i) <= abs(3 - j):
            print(abs(3 - i) + 1, end='')
        else:
            print(abs(3 - j) + 1, end='')
    print()
print_pattern()
```